# 'Corrupt' Exif data on Android Camera-X

Tags: exif, android-camerax

I've been testing a migration to Android's new Camera X library and checking the EXIF data with `exif $FILE`.
Some of the attributes are displayed, but the amount of values seems truncated & it displays an error:

```
Corrupt data
The data provided does not follow the specification.
ExifEntry: The tag 'ExifVersion' contains data of an invalid format ('ASCII', expected 'Undefined').
```

Photos from the same device using the Camera 2 API  would show all the values and list the Exif Version as:

> Exif Version | Exif Version 2.2

I thought that this was a bug with Camera X corrupting the data, but I just tried to read it with `exiftool` and it displays all fields correctly. On both Camera libraries (CameraX/Camera2), the Exif Version gets displayed as:

> Exif Version : 0220

This is happening for me on multiple devices, both e.g. a [Samsung Galaxy A01 CORE SM-A013M](https://www.phonemore.com/specs/samsung/galaxy-a01-core/sm-a013mds-16gb/) and a [Nokia 8.1](https://www.phonemore.com/specs/nokia/8-1/)

Tried Googling for the error message from `exif` about invalid formats but couldn't find anything.

Is this a bug with Camera X, Exif or both? Or is it something I can safely ignore? (Assuming though that I do need valid Exif data :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is correct: tag `0x9000` "ExifVersion" may only use the type `UNDEFINED` as per

- [the documentation from 2002, page 26](https://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) and trustful resources like
- [Exiv2](https://www.exiv2.org/tags.html) and
- [AWare Systems](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif/exifversion.html).

But any consumer can still support other datatypes, such as `ASCII` - if *exiftool* does not yield an error then it is most likely for your convenience, while at the same time you're unaware of that a violation to the standard has been encountered.

The writer produces this bug: if following the standard `UNDEFINED` as datatype must be used, nothing else. One key difference between both datatypes is: one comes with a terminating byte, the other doesn't. Likewise using `ASCII` without a terminating byte is a bug, too - and on the field "ExifVersion" it's impossible to write the literal `0220` with the needed terminating byte when the field length is defined as exactly 4 bytes already.

Effectively the difference hardly matters:

- either I interpret the binary `0x30 0x32 0x32 0x30` as 4 bytes (as per datatype `UNDEFINED`) or
- the literal `0220` (with or without a terminating `0x00`, as per dataype `ASCII`).

Even if I as consumer am still able to read it despite following the standard it should not pass by unnoticed. It's somehow like crossing a street while the traffic lights are red for you: it may work under certain conditions, but that doesn't make it okay.